# Two different named tables with same structure (GreenDAO)

Tags: android, greendao

I'm trying to create two same structure tables with greendao. So basically, I'm doing following to achieve. Create `Position.class`:

```
public class Position {

    protected double longitude;
    protected double latitude;

    public Position(double longitude, double latitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
```

And then create second class CurrentRouePosition.class

```
@Entity(
        generateConstructors = false,
        nameInDb = "CURRENT_POSITIONS"
    )
    public class CurrentPosition extends Position{

    public CurrentPosition(double longitude, double latitude) {
        super(longitude, latitude);
    }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't create DAO classes. What could I do to achieve same structure different name tables in GreenDAO?

Answer (score 0):

GreenDAO does not support Entity inheritance as of now. There are approaches to achieve something similar, but they involve using the older generator approach (which you shouldn’t use).
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/362

In general I don’t see why you want to implement another class which is exactly the same as the first. The only thing which differs is the time of insertion into the database.
Instead I would suggest to explicitly define an auto increment id to your Entity. By doing so you can query the last result (=highest id) from your DAO class which then would be your current position.

```java
@Entity
public class Position {

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    protected double longitude;

    protected double latitude;
}
```

Query current position:

```java
Position currentPosition = positionDao.queryBuilder()
    .orderDesc(PositionDao.Properties.Id).limit(1).unique();
```